# Is there a way to download .aab file from Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, proguard, android-app-bundle

I am using ProGaurd and i found that the mapping file is part of .aab file, so if some one has that mapping file can revert the code to its original form, so is there a way to download .aab file from play store or it is not downloadable from play store.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way of downloading .aab file from Play Store to your pc but you can download .aab file from third party store like [apkpure.com](https://m.apkpure.com/fr/) . They have almost all of the apps available on Play Store.

Comment: Means adding progaurd will not help as they will have the aab file and the mapping file as well

Comment: How do they get them then?

Comment: It is possible to download the .aab. Just select "original file" to download, in bundle explorer/downloads.

Comment: Correct address is https://apkpure.net/

Answer (score 1):

no, its not possible. Play Store is using AAB file for generating APK file per device, just like [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) does

Answer (score 1):

AAB stands for Android App bundle. According to Android Developer's guide, an Android App Bundle is a publishing format that includes all the resources and compiled code for an application, and defers the APK generation and signing to Google Play. AAB formats allow custom downloads for devices that request an application.

The AAB file converts it to APK and send it to the respective devices according to their required formats.

So **NO** you cannot download aab from playstore